# refresh readonly environment variable in Linux

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I have below scenario -

1. set environment variable for all users who log in to the server through profile.d
2. make this environment variable read-only so that user doesn't get to change it
3. now comes the difficult part, the value of that environment variable gets expired in 30 mins.
4. to get a fresh valid value for that environment variable, one has to re-login to the session.

I wanted to enable a self renew capability for the users without logout and re-login, to get the fresh value. How could I do that? Please help

Thank you -

Comment: I'm more curious as to how you plan to accomplish step 2.  Are you talking about a captive environment?  To renew the environment you can just "re-source" the profile that's assigning the variables.  In bash, that would be something like ```. ./.profile``` or ```source ./.profile``` where the profile in question can be at some other location (like /etc/profile) where it can't be edited.  You cannot, however, keep an interactive session from changing its own environment variables for the current session.

Comment: If it's read-only it's read-only.  if it needs to change every 30m, then it ought not be read-only.